# Change ip address

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ip-address

I am using ubuntu 10.04 ultimate edition 2.6 and I want to change my IP address (I didn't know how to check whether it's static or dynamic) these are the following entries I found in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

```
iauto lo  
iface lo inet loopback
```

How can I change my IP address?

Comment: Do you want it to be static or dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

Your Ethernet interface is not listed in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Ubuntu uses network manager. Just right-click on the network icon on the top of your screen, then edit connections.

Answer (score 1):

if you have static Ip you can set it like this:

> Edit /etc/network/interfaces

and adjust it to your needs (in this example setup I will use the IP address 192.168.0.100):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

mapping hotplug
        script grep
        map eth0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.0.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to change your external IP address.

If you are on DSL restart the modem, dial up just disconnect and reconnect.

On cable the most consistent way to get a new IP address is to spoof the mac address of the NIC connected to the internet. 
To spoof your mac address on Ubuntu edit
/etc/network/interfaces

Add this under eth0

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
       hwaddress ether 01:02:03:04:05:06
```

If you have a static IP address you need to contact your ISP or use a proxy.